# Google Drive API files setq sharedWithMe=false causes "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: google-drive-api

Is this a bug or am I entering value incorrectly?

To repeat, go to "Try it!" on google sdk files page:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

Try getting files (you'll need to authorize); then try entering sharedWithMe=false in the setQ field.

I get the following error (interesting that sharedWithMe=true succeeds):

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: A 500 error indicates a problem with the server. Why? The server's broken. There's no telling what's going on, and there's nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. ``sharedWithMe=true`` works as intended (as does just ``sharedWithMe``), but ``not sharedWithMe``, ``sharedWithMe=false`` or ``sharedWithMe!=true`` all give a HTTP 400 error...

Comment: Is this solved anywhere? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: The same problem exists with querying on `editable`.

Comment: A possible workaround is to set `Q = "'me' in owners"`.

Comment: This is not quite the same thing, though, because if you have clicked on "Add to My Drive", then it should show up with sharedWithMe=false (if that actually worked), whereas you still aren't the owner. :( :( :(

Comment: @saltface yea i also have this problem how did you fix it exactly with javascript (nodejs)?

Comment: @bluejayke I haven't worked with the Google Drive API in some time. You should be able to set the query (Q parameter) on your request object with that string.