# Google Drive SDK "sharedWithMe = false" search query not works

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get list of folders in "My Drive" and requesting "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files" with this search query:

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and 'me' in writers and sharedWithMe = false
```

But it giving this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

But when i use `sharedWithMe = true` it works fine.

Here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters not mentions anything about sharedWithMe true check is not possible. So is it intended behaviour?

Is there a better way to get folder listing of "My Drive" instead this query?

Comment: Similar question here with a workaround in the comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717592/google-drive-api-files-setq-sharedwithme-false-causes-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 0):

the correct query is
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and 'me' in writers and sharedWithMe

without  = false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).