# Google Drive API search for files only in My Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to retrieve all files in Google Drive, but only those in 'My Drive'. I tried including "'me' in owners" in the query, but that gives me tons of files in shared folders where I am the owner. I tried "'root' in parents" in the query, but that gives me back only files directly under My Drive, while I need also files under subfolders and subolders of those subolders, etc.

I tried also setting the drive parameter but in this case the query does not retrieve anything at all:

```
driveid = service.files().get(fileId='root').execute()['id']

page_token = None
my_files = list()
while True:
    results = service.files().list(q= "'myemail@gmail.com' in owners",
                                    pageSize=10,
                                    orderBy='modifiedTime',
                                    pageToken=page_token,
                                    spaces = 'drive',
                                    corpora='drive',
                                    driveId = driveid, 
                                    includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                    supportsAllDrives=True,
                                    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    my_files.extend(items)
    page_token = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break

print(len(my_files))
# This prints: 0
```

How can I get this to work?

I guess the other possibility would be to start from root, get children and recursively navigate the full tree, but that is going to be very slow. The same applies if I get all the files and then find out all the parents to check if they are in My Drive or not, I have too many files and that takes hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set pagesize to 1000 would definatly speed things up.  But whats the issue with what you have now?   I dont think i under stand **only those in 'My Drive' (not only those directly under 'My Drive', but in any part of the full tree)**

Comment: I want to get all files in 'My Drive' and all subfolders. I wrote that sentence because I have seen some answers saying use " 'root' in parents", but that gives to me only items directly under 'My Drive' and not files under the subfolders (and subfolders 
of those subfolders) of My Drive. And thanks for the pagesize advice.

Comment: Technically speaking service.files().list() will return all the files in your drive if you keep looping.   Its just not going to be in any special order your going to have to order them locally or use check the file type if its a directory then use parents to find the files in each directory and step though it like that.   I have an example of doing that but its in C# if your interested.

Comment: you may also want to consider the fact that file.list is going to return directories as well which are not really files so you might want to check the mimetype as well.

Comment: https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/  <--- List all files in C#

Comment: Right, the question is if there is any way to avoid the looping through all files and determine who is the parent afterwards (that's super slow).

Comment: I already tried what you suggest, but that gives me files in Shared Folders, not in 'My Drive', and I don't want them. There are thousands of files in Shared Folders being owned by me and looping through all of them to check who is the parent, to see if they are under 'My Drive' or some other drive takes literally hours.

Comment: try adding sharedWithMe = false in the q parameter.  The thing is you can use drive to do most of the searching for you.   Let me try to explain in an Answer i cant help with the python though.

Comment: You have the `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True` and the `supportsAllDrives=True`, have you tried setting them to false?

Comment: @dalmTo I already tried sharedWithMe = false and I get HttpError. But I guess I am doing something wrong there, because it doesn't make sense I get an error with that query. My query is: " 'user@gmail.com' in owners and  sharedWithMe = false". Also I get files in other drives where the files are not simply shared with me, but I have been made the owner

Comment: @Kessy yes, I tried that already and I get an error saying that if I want to use the drive corpus, those parameters must be True

Comment: regarding shared with me it seems it is problematic?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515151/google-drive-sdk-sharedwithme-false-search-query-not-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first request you make would be to parents in root.  This is the top level of your drive account.

```
results = service.files().list(q= "root in parents").execute()
```

Now you will need to loop though the results here in your code.  Check for mime type being a directory  `'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`  Everything that is not a directory should be a file sitting in the root directory of your Google drive account.

Now all those directories that you found what you can do is make a new request to find out the files in those directories

```
results = service.files().list(q= "directorIDFromLastRequest in parents").execute()
```

You can then loop though getting all of the files in each of the directories. Looks like its a known bug [Drive.Files.list query throws error when using "sharedWithMe = false"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759777)

## shared with me

You can also set `SharedWithMe = false` in the q parameter and this should remove all of the files that have been shared with you.  Causing it to only return the files that are actually yours.

This used to work but i am currently having issues with it while i am testing.

## Speed.

The thing is as mentioned files.list will by default just return everything but in no order so technically you could just do a file.list and add the sharedwithme and get back all the files and directories on your drive account.   By requesting pagesize of 1000 you will then have fewer requests.  Then sort it all locally on your machine once its down.

The other option would be to do as i have written above and grab each directory in turn.  This will probably result in more requests.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned at the end of the question I want to know if there is a way not having to loop. Regarding sharedWithMe that for some reason gives me HTTPError ...

Comment: Yeah i cant get sharedWithMe working either.   There is no way that i know of to not have to loop though this.   Even just doing the Files.list with 1000 page limit your still going to have to loop if you have more then a thosand.

Comment: pitty! Why is the corpora='drive' not working either? is there something missing in my query?

Comment: yep. Looping through all files and folders takes ~4 min in my case, which is not as bad as I initially thought. It would be better to have a more restrictive query as I was asking for in the question, but I guess that's not possible.

Comment: In my experience Google really only things its important to give you the data what you do with it is up to you.   SO just giving you everything and letting you sort it latter to them doesn't matter.  To us on the other hand it would be nice to only get back the data we actually want in that way speeding things up.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix here using google drive API v3 with python 3.7+

use the following syntax:

```
q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and 'me' in owners"
```

This query passed into service.files().list method should get you what you need. A list of all folders owned by you which is the best workaround I could find. " *'me' in owners*" is the key here.

Full snippet here:

```
response = service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and 'me' in owners",
                                spaces='drive',
                                fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                pageToken=page_token).execute()

for file in response.get('files', []):
    # Process change
    print ('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
```

Comment: thanks, but as I explained in the question, I do have thousands of files I own but that are not in my home folder, and I am not interested on getting those, therefore the solution has to be restricted to my home folder.

Comment: have you tried to set the parent folder to the home folder using folder id and parent parameters?

Comment: yes, that gives you the elements directly under that folder but not the subsequent elements below in a recursive way